# generate list of numbers from given set with given, length, mean, sd

Tags: python

Is there a way to generate a list of `x` numbers, drawn from a given `set` (n1,n2,n3,n4..) with an as-close-as-possible mean and standard deviation to a predefined `mu`, `sigma`?

Example:

```
>>> my_function(x = 8, s = {35.2, 43.5, 46.7, 53.6, 59.8}, mu = 47, sigma = 9)
[35.2, 35.2, 43.5, 46.7, 53.6, 59.8, 59.8, 43.5]
mean: 47.1625
sd: 9.179452258
```

The output sample does not need to be normally distributed.

Comment: Do you have a more specific definition of "as-close-as-possible"? This is especially important for getting close to *two* different numbers. Is there any limitation on the length of the result list? Are we to assume that you want only the population standard deviation  (sigma)?

Comment: @Rory Daulton _Do you have a more specific definition of "as-close-as-possible"._ Let's say within 0.5 for both m and sd should be adequate. _Is there any limitation on the length of the result list?_ Yes,  `x = 8` indicates that the output list should comprise 8 numbers.   _Which standard deviation?_ Any would do! Thank you!

Comment: The problem is equivalent to finding a set of numbers that approximately sum to `mu * x` and whose squares sum to `mu ** 2 - sigma ** 2)`. Try looking at approximations to the subset sum problem